# What gave rise to the widespread popularity of coffee?

Tags: colonization, food

What gave rise to the widespread popularity of coffee? For example, was it a marketing effort by countries with colonies that were suitable for growing coffee? Were there supposed health benefits that made it popular? Was it popularized specifically for its caffeine content?

Comment: Is this about marketing history?

Comment: No, it is really just a general question. I have often wondered how coffee became so important in many peoples' everyday life. I only mentioned marketing as one possible cause.

Comment: The fact that it was safe to drink, and most of the alternatives resulted inebriation, while coffee stimulated? Have you done any preliminary research? Consulted wikipedia?

Comment: [Uncommon Grounds: The History of Coffee and How It Transformed Our World](http://www.amazon.com/Uncommon-Grounds-History-Coffee-Transformed/dp/046501836X) by [Mark Pendergrast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Pendergrast) would be an excellent book for you to read.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: I would think that just boiling water would be simpler. Yes, I checked wikipedia, but it seemed to brief. But still, thank you for your comment. Indeed, the stimulations is probably important, but evidence would be nice. Mike: The book looks interesting. I will have a look, though according to one reviewer it focuses too much on the American story. I am a bit more curious about what made it popular at first. Thank you both.

Comment: For instance in Sweden coffee have been illegal under different periods (1756-1769, 1794–1796, 1799–1802 and 1817–1823), but it don't appear to have stopped Swedes from drinking coffee.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is kind of a broad question, but I think you should examine what people said about coffee in the early history of the beverage.

> "...it drove away fatigue and lethargy, and brought to the body a
>   certain sprightliness and vigour."

--Abd al-Qadir al-Jaziri, 1587, quoted in The World of Caffeine by Bennett Alan Weinberg, Bonnie K. Bealer.

> "A beverage as black as ink, useful against numerous illnesses,
>   particularly those of the stomach."

—Léonard Rauwolf, *Reise in die Morgenländer*, 1583, [quoted in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee).

> "That which makes for its coldnesse is its stipticknesse. In summer it
>   is by experience found to conduce to the drying of rheumes, and
>   flegmatick coughes and distillations, and the opening of obstructions,
>   and the provocation of urin. It is now known by the name of Kohwah.
>   When it is dried and thoroughly boyled, it allayes the ebullition of
>   the blood, is good against the small poxe and measles, the bloudy
>   pimples; yet causeth vertiginous headheach, and maketh lean much,
>   occasioneth waking, and the Emrods, and asswageth lust, and sometimes
>   breeds melancholly."

--Dr. Edward Pocoke, *The Nature of the Drink Kauhi, or Coffee, and the Berry of which it is Made, Described by an Arabian Phisitian*, 1659. Quoted in *[All About Coffee](http://www.cluesheet.com/All-About-Coffee-III.htm)* by William H. Ukers, 1922.

The following are also quoted in *All About Coffee*:

> "this drinke they take every morning fasting in their chambers, out of
>   an earthen pot, being verie hote, as we doe here drinke
>   aquacomposita[49] in the morning: and they say that it strengtheneth
>   and maketh them warme, breaketh wind, and openeth any stopping."

-- Bernard Ten Broeke Paludanus, 1590s

> "...Drinking a certaine liquor, which they do call Coffe, which is
>   made of seede much like mustard seede, which will soone intoxicate the
>   braine like our Metheglin."

-- William Parry, 1601

Oh, what the heck, here's a collection of the claims made about coffee around that time, from *All About Coffee*:

- "Good for the head and stomache."
- "It causeth good concoction, and driveth away drowsinesse."
- "...helpeth, as they say, digestion, and procureth alacrity..."
- "...It is very good to help Digestion, to quicken the Spirits and to cleanse the Blood."
- "...Comforteth the brain and heart, and helpeth digestion."
- "...Wholesome, they say, if hot, for it expels melancholy."
- "...dryeth ill Humours in the stomach, comforteth the Brain, never causeth Drunkenness or any other Surfeit, and is a harmless entertainment of good Fellowship."

So the point here is that you had a lot of people spreading the word about coffee -- suggesting that it drives away fatigue, but also that it had medical benefits. It's a stimulant, and people tend to like stimulants, and this one has a fairly pleasant smell when prepared -- I think word of mouth was probably enough to expand its popularity.

--

Answer (score 0):

I found the following moment interesting regarding the coffee adoption. The coffee could have been excommunicated from Catholicism but was saved by Pope Clement VIII (1535-1605) and declared as a truly Christian beverage. (Click the quote to see the context of the citation)

> ["Why, this Satan's drink is so delicious that it would be a pity to
>   let the infidels have exclusive use of it. We shall fool Satan by
>   baptizing it, and making it a truly Christian beverage."](http://buk.io/@28500/8/23428~23618?t=2CK)

by *Ukers, William H. (William Harrison)*, [All About Coffee, Gutenberg Edition](https://buk.io/@28500)

Comment: I think it's important to bear in mind that the passage refers to this story as being "according to a much quoted legend".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more a question of biology than history.  Coffee:

- Has effects that are almost entirely positive in moderate doses
- Has effects that can generally be seen as positive for society.  (I.e. makes people work harder.)
- Has no obvious negative effects
- Is addictive

A substance with those features seems destined for popularity.